# How to change permission of /root/opt while it is owned by root

Tags: permissions, root

I want to change the permission of the folder "opt" and "usr". It is owned by root. I can't change the permissions at this moment because it's showing "You're not the owner, so you cannot change the permission".

I want to change permission of inside folders too. Is there any command for that please? I'm a newbie to Ubuntu and currently having 13.04

Comment: Don't do it. Changing permissions of these system folders will cripple your system. Search this site and find questions from people who did it and then couldn't change those permissions back easily.

Comment: Changing Permissions is very Dangerous, unless you sure that what you do is correct, it's good idea to tells us why you will do that so we can help you more

Comment: Here, the real question is "why should you want do that?". Probably there is something horribly wrong in the steps *preceding* the need to ask such a (suicidal) question.

Comment: This really looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/237563)... you definitely should state what you're intending to do with this.

Answer (score 17):

First thing I will say: Do ***not*** change the ownership of `/opt` or `/usr`. You will cause masses of problems. For instance, if you change the ownership of `/usr` from root, then `sudo` will no longer work properly (in fact, it could render the computer unbootable from what I have heard). Indeed, there's very little that's owned by `root` by default that I would ever advocate changing the ownership of - once you do something like that recursively it becomes incredibly difficult to undo it.

If you need to create a file within one of them, use `sudo`. So, if you had instructions to install a program under `/opt`, in a folder called `/opt/myprogram` that needed to belong to you, you would perform the following commands;  `cd /opt`; `sudo mkdir myprogram`; `sudo chown $USER myprogram`.

But as I say, for the sake of your system's stability, ONLY change the ownership on files or folders you yourself have created. If you need to edit something owned by `root`, use `sudo` ahead of the command rather than taking ownership.

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the question, it is the best answer. You should add a howto though, even if you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @pacificfils, no, don't ask for a "howto break your system".

Comment: @Guntbert i am aware of that. I have done that once before in my Linux infancy.

Comment: @pacificfils In principle I agree, I generally dislike answers along the lines of "Why would you want to do that? That's wrong, don't do that. Do this instead" since usually they're ignoring something unsaid that the asker wants to do. But what Espero wanted to do here was a very dangerous of going about things. Technically the last step of my suggestion (workaround for what he probably wanted to do) *could* be used to do this, but I didn't want to explicitly state a possibly system-bricking command (`/opt` isn't as dangerous as `/usr`, but still...)

Answer (score -2):

If your user is in the sudoers list (/etc/sudoers) you can use sudo before the command.

`$sudo chmod 777 /root/opt`

Similarly you can use `chown` command to change the owner of a file.

But it is not recommended to grant access to anything inside /root to users other than root. Be careful!

Comment: **Never** suggest giving `777` to any directory without proper explanation and warnings.